# I don't know how to find vector derivatives in other co-ordinate systems easily.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I have been reading Electrodynamics by griffiths and I don't know how to find the gradient, curl, etc in spherical or cylindrical co-ordinates.
I need a simple method or algorithm to quickly derive all the expressions for any co-ordinate system. I don't know much linear algebra etc.
Please help, I have an exam tomorrow. I haven't been able to find the answer in simple terms anywhere. Also, if possible, please indicate where I could learn more in the future about these things.

Comment: Why were you waiting till last Date to get this Answer ??